# perl: correct `content type` formatting for returning `image data uri`

Tags: angularjs, perl, content-type, dancer

I have a template in `angularjs` expecting the `image data uri` returned by a server call invoked through the `src` attribute of the `img` element of the template:

```
<img width="200px" height="200px" src="http://localhost:3000/returnimage" />
```

On the server side, written in `Perl` with `Dancer` I have:

```
any ['get', 'post'] => '/returnimage' => sub {
    content_type 'image/jpeg;base64;';
    'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4gIcSUNDX1B....N5f2hqE//Z';
};
```

The result on template render is a broken image tag:
[image]
[image]
But the call is executed:
[image]

The network response and preview are unavailable. But if I call `http://localhost:3000/returnimage` directly from the browser they do contain the complete `image data uri` as 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4gIcSUNDX1B....N5f2hqE//Z'. ALthough a black image shows up and when inspected:

[image]

Any ideas on problem/fix ?

Comment: The `src` attribute expects an image and you provide the MIME type of an image, but you actually return a data URI containing an image, not an image itself. Can the response not return the image contents directly?

Comment: @amon The back end generates an image data uri as exampled in the returned string in the subroutine... how should it be treated to be returned successfully/functionally to the src attribute? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl subroutine:

```
my $photo = '/9j/4gIcSUNDX....oqOU1MzEFUa8x2MJf5JUjFV3llWW3UVscTLNhd93KFWQUrqHn/ABEc2CfmIASx0nMWLiN5f2hqE//Z';
my $decoded= MIME::Base64::decode_base64($photo);
content_type 'image/jpeg';
$decoded;
```