# How to serve image data uri to a src attribute via http call to perl?

Tags: javascript, html, image, perl, mime-types

This is what I have tried so far with my very little knowledge of perl...

`angularjs` `template` requests an image through `src` attribute to perl subroutine:

```
<img width="200px" height="200px" src="http://localhost:3000/returnimage" />
```

Perl(Dancer) subroutine:

```
any ['get', 'post'] => '/returnimage' => sub {

    content_type 'image/jpeg;base64;';
    'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4gIcSUNDX1B....N5f2hqE//Z';
};
```

Should I not return the data uri? should I return the image? if so how would that be done from the image data uri?

Comment: Is this Dancer?

Comment: @simbabque yes it is!

Comment: You are trying to send an inline image. What you should send is just an image. The data uri is wrong.

Comment: how to transform the image data uri to an image using perl?

Comment: Why do you have it as base64 in the first place? To get the raw image, you need to decode it. Cut it out of that data uri and then decode it. Send that with a regular content type.

Comment: the data uri is the product of an R code that generate the data uri from a plotly plot to image function... So I have to find some perl module that decodes the following bit of the data uri '/9j/4gIcSUNDX1B....N5f2hqE//Z' ?

Comment: Yes. MIME::Base64 can do that.

Comment: Is there any difference between this and [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46565373)?

Comment: i guess ine of the should be deleted...